# nlog files with a date

Tags: c#-3.0, nlog

In a C# 2008 application, I want to write the NLog error log files out so that the files have a date on them. In the example listed below, you can see that I have 3 log files. Can you tell me how place a month-day-year format on these files?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
 <configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="spring">
  <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core" />
  <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
   </sectionGroup>
   <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
   </configSections>
   <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <targets>
  <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Logs\NlogOutput.log" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this for your `fileName` parameter:

```
fileName="${basedir}/${shortdate}.log"
```

Generally speaking, you can use most NLog LayoutRenderers to help compose your filename.